# How to add an image to an event in Python's icalendar?

Tags: python, image, icalendar

I am using [icalendar](https://pypi.org/project/icalendar/) to create an ical file. I want to include an image with each event. According to [the spec](https://icalendar.org/New-Properties-for-iCalendar-RFC-7986/5-10-image-property.html) this is supported through the following format:

```
IMAGE;VALUE=URI:https://example.com/images/party.png
```

I don't get icalendar to output this. I tried this:

```
event.add('image', 'VALUE=URI:%s' % image_url)
```

And this results in the following output:

```
IMAGE:VALUE=URI:https://example.com/images/party.png
```

As you can see, the image is followed by a colon instead of a semicolon. What causes this? How can I add an image to an ical file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'VALUE=URI' part is a property parameter. So it is not to be added in the value directly. Don't know much about this particular API but you need to do something like:

```
event.add('image', image_url, parameters={'VALUE': 'URI'})
```